# Convert a VB function to Perl

Tags: perl, vbscript

Can somebody help me convert this VB function to Perl (PHP, Ruby or Python will do also)?

```
Public Function CFUSION_ENCRYPT(ByVal Password As String, ByVal Key As String) As String
  Dim NewValue As String
  Dim TempValue As String
  NewValue = ""
  For i = 1 To Len(Password)
   TempValue = Asc(Mid(Key, i, 1)) Xor Asc(Mid(Password, i, 1))
   NewValue = NewValue & Format(Hex(TempValue), "00")
  Next
  CFUSION_ENCRYPT = NewValue
End Function
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think you should try yourself, and then ask for help if you get stuck.

Comment: What happens if the password is longer than the key?

Comment: This is **not** encryption. It's at best a scramble or cypher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP:

```
function cfusion_encrypt($password, $key) {
  $new = '';
  $tmp = '';
  for($i = 0, $l = strlen($password); $i < $l; ++i) {
    $tmp = ord(substr($key, $i, 1)) ^ ord(substr($password, $i, 1));
    $new &= sprintf('%02X', $tmp);
  }
  return $new;
}
```

Please test if the result is really the same

Answer (score 2):

Well, what the heck... perl:

```
sub cfusion_encrypt
{
    my ($password, $key) = @_;

    my @p = split( //, $password );
    my @k = split( //, $key );
    my $end = $#p < $#k ? $#p : $#k;  # which is shorter, key or password?
    my @result = ();

    for my $i ( 0 .. $end ) 
    {
        push @result, sprintf('%0.2x', ord($p[$i] ^ $k[$i]));
    }

    join( '', @result );
}
```

Like @Cameron said, don't think this is good encryption. Also you may want to make sure the key is at least as long as the password.

Comment: Thanks theglauber, this is also sweet :) Thank you guys! Can I set "answer" to all? :)

Comment: You're welcome. I just realized that you wanted the output as a string of hexadecimal digits, so i fixed my code above.

Answer (score 2):

Just sort-of golfing with theglauber:

```
join( '', List::MoreUtils::pairwise { 
                $a and $b and $a ^ $b or ''; 
          } 
            @{[ split( //, $password ) ]}
          , @{[ split( //, $key ) ]} 
       );
```

Answer (score 0):

My Perl's a bit rusty, here's a Python version (untested):

```
def CFUSION_ENCRYPT(password, key):
    if len(password) > len(key):
        raise Exception('Key must be at least as long as password')

    result = ''
    for password_char, key_char in zip(password, key):
        result += '%0.2X' % (ord(key_char) ^ ord(password_char))
    return result
```

I hope you're not using this for anything that's supposed to be cryptographically strong...

Comment: Thanks Cameron, your port works good also, no I just test some historical cryptographic methods.